# Opening CakePHP to edit with Dreamweaver?

Tags: php, cakephp, dreamweaver

just a quick question, I have just done some research and I can not find a complete solution to my problem. I am using Dreamweaver CC only because I have started working with Designers and its the edit program they use. They have no PHP knowledge and they use Dreamweaver to build all there Photoshop designs.

I have found a few sites about how to add .ctp files, but it (Dreamweaver) only lets me edit the .cpt files as PHP files and not view them. I am running the CakePHP site I am using for these tests within a VM (virtual machine) locally. But although I have setup this as a live sever and I view the controller, it just loads the missing AppController message?

So are there any way of getting Dreamweaver to load and view CakePHP completely? So my designers can edit / build their designs the way they want?

I am very stocked, CC is a very new version of Dreamweaver and yes they seem to have added, LESS and SASS support (last version I used, some time ago, was CS4) and it seems very good, nice syntax highlighter. But why don't they support frameworks, its not just CakePHP, but they seem not to support any PHP based framework? I think with the use of these frameworks, lack of support is stocking!!

I will also just as a side note, I may be building Drupal powered sites for them as well, any pointers on getting that to work in Dreamweaver to?

Many thanks

Glenn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your designers (in the best of luck) use some html dummy content to create css files that style it, based on a photoshop or other mockup.

You as a developer need to turn that html to a cake or any other framework template.

There's no automated way for this to be done as no tool can do the creative thinking a human mind can do. That's why dreamweaver doesn't do it. LESS and SASS are not programming languages per se, it's a way to script common CSS which is a different thing.

I believe you shouldn't be adopting to the tools your designers use and neither should they adopt the tools that help you, as much a house builder doesn't need to use a CAD to build on a blueprint created by an architect on a CAD, neither an architect needs to know how to operate machinery. You just need a common ground to talk to each other (the blueprint or HTML/CSS).

So don't force yourself to work on dreamweaver and neither force your designers to work on a code editor. Don't expect dreamweaver to (ever?) integrate a programming IDE as that would be too bloated for both developers and designers and without any true advantages to my opinion.

Comment: I do see your point but I thought about it and yes, they could just build basic HTML / CSS however they want and give it to me or even a photoshop file and then I do the CSS / SASS (as I think it is so cool!!). But with Dreamweaver, I don't mind using it so it does mean that we r using all the same tools. Its not a bad syntax editor.

Comment: If you start with a photoshop template then you also have part of the role of a designer. A lot of us do, although you will probably find out that you'll be more comfortable with only one of the two. So it's up to you to use dreamweaver for making a HTML/CSS layout and adopt it to the framework of your choice or if you insist, even use dreamweaver as a text editor for your cakephp code. But don't expect to get the functionality of a special tool made for programmers, as you don't expect dreamweaver to have the photo editing functionality of photoshop.